# How to smooth scroll inside element with Selenium[Python]

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm using

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", element)
```

in order to scroll inside an element ( dynamically generated list). The code above is the only one I found that actually works and scrolls.
Is there any way to do a smooth scroll (instead of the actual step scroll)? I feel like I'm missing some data when it's jumping around.

Comment: Only by doing multiple scrolls a little at a time.  That's what the browser does in response to mouse wheel motion.

Comment: And how can I do that with the provided command? I know absolutely no JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Element#scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll) which allows passing an options object in which `behavior: 'smooth'` can be specified.

```py
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scroll({top: arguments[0].scrollHeight, behavior: 'smooth'})", element)
```